# Intellij - Maven Variables

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Using Maven variables doesn't seem to be working in Intellij; it is throwing an error.

My pom.xml is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</project>
```

Intellij throws the following error:
[image]

I'm still fairly new to Maven, so apologies if the answer is obvious. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're setting the attributes of the top level element using the top level element's values; why; what are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I have an archetype which should use the project name, package, etc.

Comment: Please consider, spending some times to grasp the basics of Maven See here [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

Answer (score 0):

In maven, each project is identified by a tuple (groupId, artifactId, version).

So for each project (ie each pom), theses fields are required and must be defined.

Then, you can refer to these value by putting ${project.groupId}, ${project.artifactId} and ${project.version}, but only if these fields was correctly defined for this pom.

Note that groupId and version can be also inherited from parent. In this case, if there is a parent, only setting a artifactId is really required